# Weatherbug REST JSON

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have a solid understanding of HTML and javascript.  I have no experience with JSON.  I would like to get the data from the URL http://i.wxbug.net/REST/Direct/GetUv.ashx?zip=21044&api_key=vxwdyz3evgtvuv9d5e53sckc and display it on a webpage.  I have looked around for a simple tutorial that explains how to retrieve JSON data from a URL without prevail.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you use any languages other than HTML/Javascript?  If not, you're a bit limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), especially if JSONP isn't supported.

Comment: Yes definitively, I can use languages other than HTML and Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page is in different domain, you will encounter the "**...not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" error when you use javascript to access it. However, you could make a proxy page in the server side, fetch the data and then output data.

And then, you could get the data, for example, if you use jQuery, it is very easy like:

```
$.getJSON(your_proxy_page_url,function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The idea of making a proxy page got me on the right track.  I ended up using 
<?php
    $url = 'http://i.wxbug.net/REST/Direct/GetForecastHourly.ashx?zip=21044&ht=t&ht=i&ht=d&api_key=vxwdyz3evgtvuv9d5e53sckc';
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
in order to get the JSON data as a JSON objec, then I used json_decode() to convert the JSON data to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to take look at this post, maybe it can help you out:

http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getScript